# writing uint16 Raw files

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, writetofile

I try to write a raw file with the following code:

```
OutputFile = open(OutputFilePath,'w')
BlockArray= np.array(A).astype(np.uint16)
BlockArray.tofile(OutputFile)
OutputFile.close()
```

Then I try to read it again with:

```
OutputFile = open(OutputFilePath,'r+')
print np.fromfile(OutputFile,dtype=np.uint16)
```

The problem is that the file size is correct, but the first `8192` numbers are good, but then numbers get reversed or completely wrong. The shape of the array is `(300,1312,98)`. I don't know what is happening here. So can anyone explain to me way this happens and how I can write a correct raw file?

with reversed I mean that the hex number should be for example `A5 01 = 421` but in the raw file number `01 A5 = 42241` is written.

Comment: Which version of Python?  Which OS?

Comment: python 2.7 on multiple windows 10 and 7 possibly 8

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default behavior of the `.tofile()` method is to write a *binary* file, so you must open the file that you will write to in binary mode:

```
OutputFile = open(OutputFilePath, 'wb')
```

Likewise for reading the file:

```
OutputFile = open(OutputFilePath, 'rb')
```

This is crucial in Windows because of the automatic conversion of line endings that Python does with text (i.e. non-binary) files.

Comment: I indeed saw that the problem were line endings didn't understand why they were there, but it seems to work thank you very much. Oddly enough this behavior does not applies to np.memmep. Do you know why?

Comment: @J.Goedhart: It won't apply to `np.memmap()` because that doesn't call `file.write()`.